# Copy tables with different column name MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-migration

I need to copy all rows from table1 matching specific columns into table2 with different columns name.
For example:

- table1 name = oldAddressBook , table1's columns name = Name,Surname,Number
- table2 name = newAddressBook , table2's columns name = newName,newSurname,Phone

Data in columns "Name,Surname,Number" in "oldAddressBook" must fill respectively "newName,newSurname,Phone" in "newAddressBook".  "oldAddressBook" and "newAddressBook" contain also other columns.

Comment: If the answer will help you, please select an answer..

Answer (score 11):

```
INSERT INTO newAddressBook (newName, newSurname, Phone)
SELECT name, surname, number
FROM oldAddressBook
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [insert-select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement:

```
INSERT INTO newAddressBook (`newName`, `newSurname`, `Phone`)
SELECT `Name`, `Surname`, `Number` FROM oldAddressBook;
```