# Copy Table Columns to another Table and Handle other Columns that do not Accept Null

Tags: sql-server

The answer to the first half is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753188/2093880)

```
INSERT INTO newAddressBook (newName, newSurname, Phone)
SELECT name, surname, number
FROM oldAddressBook
```

If I apply the answer as it is without modifications, I get the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Resident', table 'dbo.newAddressBook'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I would like to be able to copy columns while passing a default value, false, to a column (Resident) that does not have a match in the original table and does not accept null either.

Comment: So hard code that value in your select statement.

Comment: @SeanLange, how to hard code that? it gives me "invalid column name" since this is a select statement

Comment: You use a constant instead of a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this. Since Resident does not allow null you must provide a value. You can do this with a literal value.

```
INSERT INTO newAddressBook (newName, newSurname, Phone, Resident)
SELECT name, surname, number, 'false'
FROM oldAddressBook
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a CASE WHEN statement?

```
INSERT INTO newAddressBook (Resident)
SELECT (CASE WHEN Resident IS NOT NULL THEN Resident ELSE 'False' END)
FROM oldAddressBook
```

Comment: I think that won't work because the CASE statement is assuming that Resident is an oldAddressBook column, which it is not.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Didn't know where the column was coming from as it wasn't in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO newAddressBook (Resident)
SELECT ISNULL(Resident, 'Default') As Resident
FROM oldAddressBook

In above example if resident value is Null then 'Default' value will be inserted in newAddressBook.